# Matrix derivatives, trace and inverse

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative

I'm reading a paper where I encountered the following equation
$$
-{1\over 2}{\partial \over \partial\theta_i} \text{tr}\left(\left(\mathbf{zz}^\top \odot T\right) (\Sigma \odot T )^{-1} \right)
 =
-{1\over 2}\text{tr}\left(\left(\mathbf{zz}^\top \odot T\right) (\Sigma \odot T )^{-1}\left({\partial \over \partial\theta_i} \Sigma \odot T \right)(\Sigma \odot T )^{-1} \right)
$$
such that $\Sigma(\theta)$ and $T$ are $n\times n$ symmetric real-valued matrices, $z$ is a $n \times 1$ real-valued vector and $\theta$ is a  real-valued scalar. Only $\Sigma(\theta)$ depends on the parameter $\theta$.

Shouldn't it be
$$
-{1\over 2}\left(\mathbf{zz}^\top \odot T\right) (\Sigma \odot T )^{-1}\left({\partial \over \partial\theta_i} \Sigma \odot T \right)(\Sigma \odot T )^{-1} 
$$
on the RHS of the expression as  ${\partial \over \partial X} tr(AX)=A^\top$ and then we get the rest through the derivative of the inverse?

Comment: The result from the paper is correct, except that the sign on the RHS should be positive instead of negative.

Comment: @greg cool! could you give me directions on how to show it ,please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ease of typing, use a dot to denote derivatives wrt $\theta$ and define the matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\S{\Sigma}\def\a{\alpha}\def\l{\lambda}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\T{\,{\rm tr}}
M &= T\odot zz^T \\
S &= T\odot\S \qiq \dot S = T\odot\dot\S \\
}$$
Recall that the trace is linear, i.e.
$$\T(A+\a B) = \T(A) + \a\T(B)$$
So its derivative is
$$\eqalign{
\frac{d\T(S)}{d\theta}
 &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\T(S+h\dot S)-\T(S)}{h} \\
 &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\T(\dot S)}{h} \;=\; \T(\dot S) \\
}$$
Use this result to differentiate the objective function
$$\eqalign{
\l &= -\frac 12\T\LR{S^{-1}M} \\
\dot\l &= -\frac 12\T\LR{-S^{-1}\dot S\:S^{-1}M} \\
 &= {{\bf +}}\frac 12\T\LR{MS^{-1}\dot S\:S^{-1}} \\
}$$

Comment: but why is $\dot{\lambda}$ equal to that? I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: The inverse matrix was already fine for me. I don't get it why the derivative of the trace becomes the trace of the inverse derivative times $M$. The book I consulted says that ${\partial \over \partial X} tr(AXB) = A^\top B^\top$, so using the chain rule, $\dot{\lambda} = {\partial \over \partial S} tr(S^{-1}M) {\partial \over \partial \theta} S^{-1}$, I'm missing something in this part.

Comment: @BelwarDissengulp Remember that the trace is linear (see the above update).

Comment: Now I get it, thanks!!